# Backbone.js – changes to li element don't display immediately

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

What I have in my template is just a bunch of divs and a list, consisting of multiple li elements. The use case is simple, the li elements are a dropdown and are displayed only on clicking a button. When the dropdown is visible and someone begins to type, the matching li element should be selected, or there should be a visual indication.

My approach is this, on a keyup event, I look for the typed word (this is quite easy) in the li elements. I find a few elements, which I've confirmed. Now, when I try to do something with these elements, nothing seems to happen WHILE the dropdown is open (right now, I'm trying to .toggle()) these elements. Now, when I click the button again (which showed the dropdown in the first place) (this click hides the dropdown), and then click the same button again to reveal the dropdown, voila! The values have been changed as they should be – the matching elements have been hidden/shown.

This has me stumped. For company policies, I can't upload the code up here, but I'll be very thankful if someone else has had this problem before and can help me out.

EDIT:
Code: function to change the dropdown on keypress, this is being fired correctly:

```
        filterOptionsForKeypress: function (event) {
        var typedString = this.$('input.filter-button-text').val(),
            searchToken = _.trim(typedString.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, '_')),
            matchingLi = this.$("li[data-field^='" + searchToken + "']", this.$el), // makes no difference with or without the context, this.$el
            that = this;
        if (matchingLi && matchingLi.length) {
            this.$(matchingLi[0]).html('kaka'); // this change shows only if the dropdown is hidden + shown again
            console.log('trying to move focus', this.$(matchingLi[0]).attr('data-field'));
        }
        // this.$el.append('Some text'); -- this works, I see the changes as they happen
    }
```

And the template looks something like this:

```
            <div class="filter-button filter-option {{if !model.include}}button-red{{else}}button-green{{/if}} toggle-dropdown" data-dropdown-class="{{if !model.include}}button-red{{else}}button-green{{/if}}">
            <div class="filter-button-text">${model.option}</div>
            <div class="filter-drop"></div>
            <div class="dropdown filter-dropdown">
                <ul>
                    {{each model.config.options}}
                        <li data-field="${$value.op}" data-include='${$value.include}'>${$value.name}</li>
                    {{/each}}
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

EDIT #2:
When the dropdown is open, this is how the html looks:
OPEN:
[image: Dropdown open]
CLOSED:
[image: Dropdown closed]

So basically, apart from adding a few styles to the enclosing div and a class 'open', I don't see any differences.

Comment: How are you getting the <li> views into the DOM? It seems like you're losing context somewhere.. like the view's that build the <li>'s aren't connected to the DOM and maybe you're rendering them incorrectly. **What's the code look like when you click the dropdown to show/hide the list?**

Comment: I'm not sure. You are directly manipulating the DOM. I'm really not sure why it wouldn't update as soon as you do `.html('kaka')` that's bizarre.

Comment: @CoryDanielson I've added the screenshots

Comment: If you could show us the code in your render method that would help. I suspect that you are editing the contents of your view, but your view is not the thing on screen (if that makes sense).

Comment: @Tom I don't see render being triggered when the dropdown is hidden/shown at all. Also, when an li element is clicked (from the dropdown) a selectOption method is triggered and logging the values of the selected li field in there (since it has been changed) shows the changed values and not the old values. Then hiding and showing the dropdown again shows the updated values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that we're using a plugin for dropdown menus. So basically, what we saw on the screen wasn't what we found selecting with this.$(). The solution? Look globally and with a :visible filter voila, problem solved.

Comment: That's good that that solves your issue.  However, it's a bit of a dangerous path to go down. What you've basically got now is some stuff stored in global scope (the DOM) that your view is calling out to. If your application is going to grow in size significantly from where it is now, I would strongly recommend trying to avoid doing global DOM lookups.

Comment: @Tom I completely agree. However, we face the same issue as many startups out there: we have too much on our platter right now and we're probably not as careful about the best practices. As a developer, I personally am in favour of doing things right, right from the start. But in a team, we all have to adjust and make do.